# openpyxl は xls 形式のファイルに対応していますか？

Tags: python, python3

openpyxlでExcelのxlsを開くことは可能でしょうか。
下記のコードだとエラーが表示されます。

Error

```
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support the old .xls file format, please use xlrd to read this file, or convert it to the more recent .xlsx file format.
```

Code

```
import openpyxl

# Excelファイルを開く
v_wb=openpyxl.load_workbook("test.xls")
```

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。

お手数ですが、宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: エラーに出ている通りで、`.xlsx` に変換して処理するのが一番手っ取り早いと思います。`.xls` でなければいけない強い理由はありますか？

Comment: そもそも文書のタイトルからして対象外なのだから他の手段に切り替えるか、.xlsxに変換してから扱った方が良いのでは？ [openpyxl - A Python library to read/write Excel 2010 xlsx/xlsm files](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), [PythonでExcelファイルを扱うライブラリの比較](https://note.nkmk.me/python-excel-library/)

Comment: 皆さん、ご回答ありがとうございます。
仰る通りで`.xlsx`に変換したらできました。ただopenpyxlで対応しているか。知りたかったです。

Comment: そうであれば質問のタイトルや内容も「対応しているか」を問うような文面にした方が伝わりやすいと思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。修正いたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下記の方法で解決しました。
openpyxlの方は、xlsに対応していないため
pyexcelを利用してxlsからxlsxへ変換致しました。

Code

```
import pyexcel as p

p.save_book_as(file_name="test.xls",
dest_file_name="test.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> openpyxl does not support the old .xls file format
> ```

と質問の中にすでに答えが書いてあると思うのですが。

Comment: ありがとうございます。対応していないです。。。